# Create Keynote presentation automatically

Tags: macos, keynote

At the introduction of Keynote in 2003 they said that Keynote presentations would be a XML-based open file format and so, keynote presentations could be created programmatically by 3rd party applications.
Is this still possible in Keynote 6.2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Until Keynote 6, this was true. However, Keynote 6 uses packages for storing keynotes:

```
test.key
├── Data
├── Index.zip
├── Metadata
│   ├── BuildVersionHistory.plist
│   ├── DocumentIdentifier
│   └── Properties.plist
├── preview-micro.jpg
├── preview-web.jpg
└── preview.jpg
```

This doesn't stop you from creating older-style XML keynotes, since Keynote 6 is backwards compatible.